# Specify existing foreign key for O2O relation in TypeORM

Tags: node.js, typeorm

Take the two entities defined at http://typeorm.io/#/one-to-one-relations

A one-to-one relation is defined in User and as a result a foreign key column "profileId" is generated in the User table. So far, so good.

But my "User" entity already has an "idProfile" column and I would like this to be the foreign key on which the relation is built. How can I tell TypeORM to use this column instead of generating a new one?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can pass the column name to [`@JoinColumn()`](http://typeorm.io/#/relations/joincolumn-options):

```
@Entity()
class User {
  @OneToOne(type => Profile)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'idProfile' })
  profile: Profile
}

@Entity()
class Profile {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: But how can you add this value to the db? When I try to add an entry with the FK (for example your idProfile) I get the error Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'DeepPartial<Promise<Issue>>'